# How to make layout consistent for small and large screens ?There's is always some whitespace left

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

How can i make a layout to fit on all screen sizes ?

I am trying to achieve this by putting the widgets inside a relative layout but at the bottom , i always see some whitespace in the **bottom**.

Till some extent i can make this work by adding top margin in the last widget so that the remaining space gets occupied.

But it's not the best way to do i think because on the smaller screen sizes the widgets tend to disappear in the bottom.

**Please see the screen shot of the layout here**
[image: Screenshot of the LAYOUTs]
Here's the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_fit_employess"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.thebitshoes.classproject.FitEmployess">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="213dp"
                android:layout_height="141dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/adios"
                android:id="@+id/adios"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email_tv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="E-mail"
                android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/adios"
                />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/pass_tv"
                android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:layout_below="@+id/email_tv"
                />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pass_tv">

        <Button
            android:text="Login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
            android:id="@+id/login_btn"
            android:onClick="loginNow"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/newuser"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/n_user_tv"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"

            />

        <TextView
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/signup_tv"
            android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.33" />
    </LinearLayout>





    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where is the xml ?
And try using weights instead of margins ..

Comment: Sorry ,now it's here .

Comment: I am not sure what is making you fill the screen, But according to material design rules, unnecessary filling of screen must be avoided. Make you widgets aligned one after the other without bothering about the empty space.

Comment: You must be actually bothered when something goes out of the screen. But for screens like login, register or lists, empty screens shouldnt pull away your time.

Comment: Please see the screenshot in the question post. The I don't exactly want to fill, but to distribute the widgets evenly in all screen sizes. Please have a look at the image. That's what i am trying to show

Comment: First remove this _android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"_ also no need to apply weight for `Button` and TextView `s` in `LinearLayout `just simple use height as `wrap_conent` and apply padding to them.

Comment: I am trying to achieve consistency in my design . How can i make it work . The layout changes everytime

Comment: I saw the image and I am saying according to that. Email and password textsixe should be 16sp, login button size should be 48dp with 12 or 14 sp text centered, new user indicator should be 12 sp, Signup text should be 16sp. And most important thing, spacing between all should be 8dp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can always use Weights properly that cover up the whole screen (try not giving margins because they tend to screw the weights when inflated on small devices)

Here is a sample code rewritten for your xml :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/activity_fit_employess"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:weightSum="2">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.3"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/adios"
        android:layout_width="213dp"
        android:layout_height="141dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email_tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="E-mail"
        android:text="email_tv"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pass_tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
        android:text="pass_tv"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pass_tv"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Login"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/n_user_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=" newuser"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/signup_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And Here is a screen shot of above xml when viewed on different devices:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for providing this answer. It perfectly solves the issue . The thing i understood is that we should work around weights to make the layout consistent.!!

Comment: Yes and one more thing always test your layout for both landscape and portrait because you may want different weights for different orientations..

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to eliminate that whitespace?    There's really no point in doing so.

If you really want to you can anchor your bottom element (or a few of your bottom elements) to the bottom of the screen.  But that will just add whitespace in the middle.  WHat you want isn't really possible-  you have different sized screens and the same sized content.  Some of those screens won't be totally full.  All you can do is pick where the extra space will be.

Comment: Totally agree with Point -1, No need to eliminate spaces, only suggestion I can give is follow the material design guide for simple screens like login/register

Comment: I want equal distribution of whitespace between the elements below password. I don,t want space left in the bottom of the screen

Comment: If you want that-  put in a linear layout with match_parent height below the password and aligned with the parent bottom.  Put each element you want to take equal space inside with a height of 0dp and a weight of 1.  And give them gravity="center".  This should make them equal size, but put the content of each view in the center of that space.  (If gravity doesn't work, use layout_gravity-  I always forget which is which).

Comment: How can i anchor my 3 widgets ,namely : Login, new user , signup at the bottom wit equal space between them? Do i need to put it inside a relative layout and then provide a top margin ?